# constraint layout inside scrollview white space at bottom?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: You can see here Extra Space after submit]I am using Scroll View inside constraint layout and it generate white space at the bottom 
 XML code  [Here](https://paste.ee/p/4uxM8)

Comment: Provide screen shot also of exact behaviour.

Comment: @jaydroider now you can see image having extra space after submit button

Comment: @HarshSinghal can you show what would you like. I see how it's now but don't understand which `white space` you want to avoid.

Comment: @HarshSinghal Doesn't understand which `white space` you need to remove. Remark it with differ. What change do you need in present behavior ?

Comment: What do you want there instead of white space?

Comment: sry i mean to say that blank space below  submit and reset button .

Answer (score 4):

Just add `android:fillViewport="true"` in the ScrollView works for me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue for me was that in the constraint view, I connected on of the elements to the bottom of the screen. Do not connect any of the UI elements to the bottom. Only use the left, right, and top sides of the screen to set the constraints for all the elements. This solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Change root `Scroll View` `height` to `match_parent` will do that.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">
```

Comment: @HarshSinghal May be some of views in between are not showing correctly.

Comment: might be. i have search everywhere but didnt find proper solution

Answer (score 0):

this bug was fixed in com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta3, but some other bugs added - for example after shared element transition constraint braking for my list element